# Is there any way to get the correct size of a string using sizeof function with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor, function-pointers, smart-pointers

```
int main() {
    char *s = "hello world!";
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(s));
}
```

I know it will return the size of the pointer. But I want to know is there any way of get the length of a string using sizeof function with pointers.
*I don't want you to use (char s[] ) s as an array take it as a pointer*
Please reply as soon as possible. I also don't want to use `strlen()`.

Comment: Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string.

Comment: Can you please explain *why* you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single object or a first element of an array.

Consider the following example

```
char *p;
char c = 'A';

p = "Hello";
p = &c;
```

As it is seen the same pointer can point to the string literal "Hello" (its first character) that has the type `char[6]` and to the single character c.

Usually when a character array is passed to a function it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. However if you will pass a pointer to the whole array then you can use the sizeof operator to determine its size.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char (*p)[6] )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );
}

int main( void )
{
    f( &"Hello" );
}
```

But such an approach has a drawback that in the declaration of the function parameter you have to specify preliminary the size of the accepted array by reference.

So a general approach is declaring function with additional parameter that specifies the size of the passed array if it is required to know the size of the array within the function.

Take into account that a string can be contained in a character array that has much more size than it is required to store the string. So to determine the size of a string itself you should use the standard string function `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char s[] = "hello world!";
    printf("%s -> %zu\n", s, sizeof s - 1);
}
```

You need to declare `s` **as an array**, not as a pointer, `sizeof` operator, applied to a pointer, gives you the size of a pointer variable, which is not the size of an array (and it is not what you want).
As you see, I initialize the array in the declaration, so I don't need to put the size between the brackets (this doesn't function with an assignment statement, it must be a declaration with an initializer)  And then I subtract one to the size of the array, as the `sizeof` operator gives me the size of the array (not the string length), and this includes the space for the `\0` character at the end.

When you run it:

```
$ a.out
hello world! -> 12
$ _
```